# Obtaining letsenrypt certificate with Node.js+Express.js

Tags: express, certbot

We cannot stop out production server to renew Let's Encrypt certificate (but we can restart it with a near zero downtime to load the new certificate). Can we configure express.js routing to get certbot working (from cron every two months)?

Comment: I used [this tutorial](https://code.lengstorf.com/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/). Worked well for me. There is a bit on auto-renewing certs with cron.

Comment: @Carson this tutorial uses nginx and standalone modes, I need to use running node+express server with webroot to get the certificate.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I should have read your question more carefully.